# Export dataframe to excel file using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have dataframes as output and I need to export to excel file. I can use pandas for the task but I need the output to be the worksheet from right to left direction. I have searched and didn't find any clue regarding using the pandas to change the direction .. I have found the package xlsxwriter do that

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
format_right_to_left = workbook.add_format({'reading_order': 2})
worksheet1.set_column('A:A', 20)
worksheet1.right_to_left()
worksheet1.write(new_df)
workbook.close()
```

But I don't know how to export the dataframe using this approach ..

snapshot to clarify the directions:
[image]

[image]

** I have used multiple lines as for format point

```
myformat = workbook.add_format()
myformat.set_reading_order(2)
myformat.set_align('center')
myformat.set_align('vcenter')
```

Is it possible to make such lines shorter using dictionary ..for example?

Comment: What do you mean by `worksheet from right to left direction`? Your expected output is not particularly clear to me.

Comment: If you know excel and VBA there is a property DisplayRightToLeft and it is assigned to True or False. I have found it in xlsxwriter package `worksheet1.right_to_left()` ..It is responsible for displaying the worksheet from left to rigth (this is the default) but as for Arabic, we are accustomed the direction from right to left.

Comment: Posted snapshots for more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import xlsxwriter

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_excel.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1') # Assuming you already have a `df`

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format_right_to_left = workbook.add_format({'reading_order': 2})
worksheet.right_to_left()
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As for such a line in VBA `ws.Cells.ReadingOrder = xlRTL` makes the Arabic numbers appear correctly. What is the equivalent here?

Comment: I have searched and could do that `worksheet.set_column('A:G', 11, format_right_to_left)`. How can I add more formats? such as this `cell_format.set_align('center')`. How can I merge the formats ??

Comment: I have updated my question so as to make it clear as for the format point.